# Central aligning nested items using Foundations 'Flex Grid'

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

With the Flex Grid of Foundation 6, I'm trying to centrally align a child  of a parent ele that has been centrally aligned with Foundation's 'align-center' class.

The parent .row uses Flex Box to align (justify) the content of its children. How do I apply central alignment to the ele on line 4, using the Framework?

Notes:

1. The 'align-self-center' on line 4 has no effect.
2. In-line styling used for sample/readability only.
3. Applying 'margin:auto' to line 4 resolves the issue, however would not in the case of using an img.

   ```
   <section class="row expanded align-middle align-center" style="height: 100%;">
   <div class="columns small-7 medium-4">
       <h3 class="text-center">lakakakaka</h3>
       <div class="align-self-center" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background: pink;"></div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
   ```

In the case of using an img, applying a wrapper as a column and setting margin: auto also achieves the desired effect, but surely theres a better way to do this?

```
<section class="row expanded align-middle align-center" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="columns small-7 medium-4">
        <h3 class="text-center">lakakakaka</h3>
        <div class="row columns small-6" style="margin:auto">
            <img src="..." alt="..." style="width: 100%;" />
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, .row is a flex parent so .columns are flex children. To make a .column a flex parent so that it's children can be aligned, you need some CSS like

```
.align-middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

We wrote a lesson on this recently that will help https://zurb.createsend.com/campaigns/reports/viewCampaign.aspx?d=y&c=E5D5A5C6700B86DC&ID=3053EAAD5186C206&temp=False&tx=0